# О заголовке на «Мете»

Tags: грамотная-речь, заголовок, речевая-избыточность

***Поздравляем с десятилетием сайта!*** — праздничный синий "плакатик" мне нравится.

А вот [заголовок](https://rus.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/567/%D0%93%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%89%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82%D0%B0-10-%D0%BB%D0%B5%D1%82?cb=1) на "Мете": ***Годовщина создания сайта — 10 лет!***
Мне *кажется*, что в формулировке имеется неточность (тавтология? плеоназм?).
Десятая годовщина — это верно; десятилетняя годовщина — неверно.
Разрешите мои сомнения: есть ли в заголовке речевая избыточность?

Comment: Десятилетняя годовщина... Это из какого-то другого заголовка.